# can't repeat an hexadecimal html entity in react jsx value props

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, flowtype

So my question is why does this work and displays dots :

```
<Field label="Password" value="&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;" type="password" />
```

And the above just displays the plain hexa code !

```
<Field label="Password" value={`${'&#x2022;'.repeat(10)}`} type="password" />
```

My Field component :

```
function renderValueByType(value: string, type: string) {
  switch (type) {
    case 'phone':
      return phoneFormatter(value);

    default:
      return value;
  }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param {*} param0 
 */
const Field = ({ label, value, type, className }: PropTypes) => (
  <div className={className}>
    <span className="Field__label">{label}</span>
    <span className="Field__content">{renderValueByType(value, type)}</span>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Interesting question. I don't have an idea why but can you try assigning ``${'&#x2022;'.repeat(10)}`` to a variable and using it as a value? I wonder how that is going to behave.

Comment: the same result with a variable function return or whatever ...

Comment: which library is `Field` component from?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: What does the two options compile to?

Comment: Strange. Try this once if it helps.`value={'&#x2022;'.repeat(10)}`

Comment: I think this is related to how react works. When you set a hard-coded string react trusts that string and inserts it to the virtual dom with a method like `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but when you use a possible dynamic value with `{}` it doesn't trust the value and doesn't render it to html and prints it as it is. This is just an idea tho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set a static string as a prop it will be rendered as is.

If you set a variable as a prop it will be sanitized.

Your best bet here is convert your hex char code to string before passing it down to your component (using `String.fromCharCode()`):

```
<Field
   label="Password"
   value={String.fromCharCode("0x2022").repeat(10)}
   type="password"
/>
```

Comment: The template literal is actually not needed here. `value={String.fromCharCode("0x2022").repeat(10)}` works the same.